# Execute script when other app is calling for a "registered file type" (like .mp4)

Tags: windows-7, windows, script, file-association, file-types

I'm experimenting on Windows 7 and need little assistance.

I've got an app that's listing my duplicates, it's the best I've found. BUT it doesn't show the filenames, only the option to "remove" them.

It does contain the function to "open" the file, but instead of opening with the corresponding program (VLC), I thought I would write I short script that simply pops up an information popup with the correct path & filename.

The idea is simple, make Windows to start the script instead of the "default" application.

My problem is that I have no idea how to tell Windows to run a script instead of loading VLC when something is calling the player for .mp4 (for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First open Registry Editor.
- Go to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mp4` key.
- Make note of the `(Default)` value.
- Use the `(default)` value identified above and navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<default value>\shell\open\command`.
- Modify the `(Default)` value found here. This value is what will be executed when an .mp4 is executed. It will look like this `"C:\SomeFolder\MyScript.bat" "%1"`. Note that those two items are surrounded by a double-quote. This prevents spaces in the paths and filenames from causing issues.

*Tip*: The `"%1"` in the value contains the full path and filename of the .mp4. It will be passed as the first argument to the script file.

Comment: +1 for the answer but this has the side affect of forcing a right-click and “open with” on any .mp4 the OP actually wants to open and play. The question is actually asking how to make one program open with a different mechanism.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, because under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mp4` are several sub "directories". and do you mean `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mp4\shell\open\command` , that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Appleoddity is this for right click? I wanted to tell windows to always use the script as soon as anything calls for the .mp4 application..

Comment: @JoBe changing this registry entry will cause the script to run in ALL circumstances when the .mp4 file is clicked or executed. You asked if you could get a single app to use a script rather than VLC Player. At least that’s what I understood. As long as you don’t mind the extra steps of right-clicking an .mp4 and then choosing “open with” and choosing “VLC player” when you actually want to play an .mp4 then this solution is right.

Comment: @Appleoddity no, I want the script to intercept all requests for .mp4 .mkv .avi and so on.. instead of vlc

Comment: @JoBe go to the key as default value in .mp4 such as mp4file

Comment: @JoBe It was a little confusing. I edited it for clarity.

Comment: @Appleoddity basically I want to set the associations to open a script instead of an app..

Comment: but must setting a .vbs script as "default" app isn't working, that causes a "not a valid 32bit program"

Comment: @jobe Because you need to execute a .vbs script with cscript.exe or wscript.exe.

Comment: @Appleoddity yeah, I just realized that 

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty easy,
open:

Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations

There you can easily change what program / script that are going to be started when you click in any files